# Rvest Scraping the correct date with xpath or html selector on IMDB

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest

I was trying to scrape a birthdate of an actor from IMDB.

I don't get to recieve the same result as it is provided in the original code

Birthdate provided in the code and desired format: "yyy-mm-dd"

```
library(rvest)
link = "https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000093/"
page = read_html(link)

Date <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="name-born-info"]/time') %>% html_text('')
```

Do I need to select another node??

Thanks!

no luck with these:

```
Date <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[3]/time') %>% html_attr('')

Date <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[3]/time') %>% html_text('')

Date <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="name-born-info"]/time') %>% html_attr('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just retrieve the single node and then add the actual attribute name into html_attr. I would also switch to faster css type selector

```
Date <- page %>% html_node('time') %>% html_attr('datetime')
```

Failing that you can regex it out

```
str_match(page %>% html_text(),'birthDate":\\s?"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})"' )[1,2]
```